# Root SGS3 with stock recovery

Tags: rooting, samsung-galaxy-s-3, updates, recovery-mode, zip

I'm going to stay on topic and make the long story short. My phone (International **Galaxy S3**) has its **USB port broken** and can't replace it because I messed it up when I was on it. Since then I use an external battery charger.
Now I need to root my phone and flash a custom recovery and since the easy way (Odin) is with USB I have to try something else.
I have already tried rooting with different apps (Framaroot, towelroot, KingRoot) with no success.

I have been reading on internet to figure out a way to **root it or flash a custom recovery** but everything comes into a dead end.
One of the possible solution I have found is rooting phone via Android **Stock Recovery** (the 3e one), but this would require a **signed update.zip**. Is this possible or it could hard-brick my phone? If it is possible, how do I make it?

The zip file needs to be signed and have a certain folder organization (META-INF and system). I could sign it with an app I discover in xda forums called Sign'em (can this work out?). But I have no idea about folder organization of the update.zip file. I downloaded a file called "Update-SuperSU" from chainfire's website which comes with META-INF folder but instead of system there are 3 extra folders: common, arm and x86. Is it the same?

If there is another way to root the phone or flash a custom recovery to do so, please tell me. Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Have you tried [this](https://www.droidmen.com/how-to-root-samsung-galaxy-s3-without-a-computer/)? It is a `CWM_SuperSU.zip` file contains both `custom recovery` and `su binaries`

Comment: Also which Android version are you on? [This guide here](http://trueandroid.com/how-to-root-samsung-galaxy-s3-gt-i9300-without-pc/) claims to root the phone with latest firmware.

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply. That first guide says I need CWM recovery installed, which I don't (Stock 3e Recovery). Also the zip is a link to chainfire's zip which includes Odin and the .tar. I'm on 4.3 Official (latest OTA update available). And I have already mentioned I tried KingRoot method of that 2nd guide and didn't work for me

Comment: If by broken you mean, the usb port was knocked loose from fhe board, then you'll need to get it soldered back in place if possible. Without some kind of existing root you cannot dump or write an *.img [recovery,boot,etc.]

Comment: @moonbutt74 When I was replacing the usb port I messed it up with solderer, and I think that place of the PCB is non-fuctional now. So if I sign an update.zip with the rooting requiered files and then flash with Stock 3e Recovery, that won't work?

Comment: J, as far as i know you need the manufacturer's private key to sign that zip as "official". While you could get a hold of a copy of your stock recovery and dissasemble it to get the keys file , i'm not sure you can generate a valid signature. You'll need to scour XDA as there are a few projects but most/all involve private keys generated by users for signature verification via custom recovery builds. Otherwise you're dead in the water. The only other option is doing some hardcore hardware hacking/surgery to manage/repair the board.

Comment: @moonbutt74 yes, I found some projects on XDA to sign zips. I don't know if that will work on stock recovery. [Sign'em](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1966007) claims to work with stock recovery. And [here](http://androidforums.com/threads/merit-root-update-zip-root.676258/) is a signed update.zip I found that claims to work with stock recovery but its for another phone model. Maybe it is possible or am I wrong? If I sign an update.zip, and try to flash it, is there any sort of danger of bricking my phone?